# How to connect to TLS 1.2 enabled URL with Java

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

How to connect to TLS 1.2 enabled URL using HTTP POST Method.

Comment: What JRE are you using and do you have so far. Are you using SE or EE?

Comment: @ChristopherMaggiulli i can use java 1.7/1.8 SE.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Java 8

> Java 8 will use TLS 1.2 by default

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/jdk-8-will-use-tls-12-as-default

So for Java 8 all you need to do is the following.

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.net.URL;

URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

## Java 7

> Java 7 needs to be set manually

```
import java.security.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.net.URL;


URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");

SSLContext ssl = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2"); 
ssl.init(null, null, new SecureRandom());

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(ssl.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: Java 7: what can I do for  a SOAPConnectionFactory connection?

Comment: You can try System.setProperty(“https.protocols”, “TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2”); if that doesn't work let me know and I will see how we do it at work. You might need to modify the java.security file but add that system property as a first attempt and follow up with me