# Is a Java 8 URL connection using TLS by default?

Tags: java, security, https

I have a short question about HTTPS/TLS and Java 8 or higher.
Imagine the following setting:

```
Version 1:
URL myUrl = new URL("https://example.com/fileOfInterest");
URLConnection connection = myURL.openConnection();
InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
```

Is this connection TLS encrypted by default (including Certificate Validation by trusted CAs and so on) or do i have to follow the guide linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44788781/how-to-connect-to-tls-1-2-enabled-url-with-java) implicating this configuration:

```
Version 2:
URL url = new URL("https://example.com/fileOfInterest");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
InputStream iStream = connections.getInputStream();
```

I am a little bit confused as Version 2 seems not to have any configurational effect on a possible HTTPS connection.

In case of having the secure HTTPS connection by default, is a fallback to unsecure HTTP in case of not being able to connect via HTTPS also prohibited? Or do i have to disable this on my own.

Thanks in advance if you could clarify this confusion, I just don't want to risk a security breach ;)

Comment: If you provide an https URL you are getting an https connection, that is by definition no matter what classes you use for type casting. If you use a protocol that is unknown to Java you are getting an Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am a little bit confused as Version 2 seems not to have any configurational effect on a possible HTTPS connection.

But of course it doesn't.

> `HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();`

This construct is called a **cast operator**: It takes the form of `(someType) someExpression`.

It does 3 **completely and utterly** unrelated things. Hence, no wonder: It confuses java programmers rather often.

The mode you're using here is the 'type coercion' mode: This is the mode you get when the type in the parens does not contain generics different from the expression (it doesn't contain any generics at all, so, check), and isn't a primitive (it's not, so check).

This mode means, **nothing happens**. The code is almost a complete no-op. At runtime, if the expression is in fact of the stated type (it turns out that it is a `HttpsURLConnection`), then nothing happens whatsoever. If it is *not*, however, that code will throw a ClassCastException.

Version 2 doesn't throw that, thus proving that **it did nothing**. (At compile time, it does, of course, coerce the type: The compiler now lets you invoke stuff that only HttpsURLConnection has on this expression whereas if you don't cast, the compiler will refuse to compile that. But, that's compile time, and when I say, 'it does nothing', I'm talking about what happens at runtime.

Given that it does nothing, and given that java is strictly dynamic dispatch (meaning, the `getInputStream()` call is always 'resolved' to the most specific implementation based on what the instance you're invoking it on actually is), these 2 snippets are **entirely equal**, unless the `openConnection` call doesn't return a `HttpsURLConnection`, in which case version 1 works and version 2 throws a ClassCastException.

This brings us to the following conclusions:

1. These 2 things do the same thing by definition, thus proving version 2 is not 'neccessary'.
2. Nevertheless version 2 can be considered 'safer', in the sense that the second one will crash (though, with an entirely inappropriate exception; you should catch it and rethrow to something more appropriate - indicating the fact that your code was specced to abort if the URL isn't https), though it doesn't apply here, of course: Your URL *IS* https-based.
3. Really, this entire API kinda sucks. Since, um, jdk11? Something more recent than jdk8 in any case, there's a new, much nicer HTTP client baked into java. [I suggest you use that one](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html).

Comment: Thank you, this makes it more precise for me. But regarding the TLS thing, do you know whether Java builds up HTTPS connections or not whilst providing a https URL ?

Comment: .  Yes, it does.